# onPageFinished not called on real device when no internet connection

Tags: android, android-webview, webviewclient

recently I have implemented a WebView for my app. I have override the `onPageFinished` function of WebViewClient and it works fine most of the time. But when I tested it on real device (Samsung S10), and turned off the internet connection, the code from `onPageFinished` is not called. In fact, all functions I overrided in `WebViewClient` are not called.

I have tested on emulators and it worked as intended. But on my physical device, the code is not executed. Also, the error code is `net:ERR_FAILED` instead of `net:ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED`.

So what is the problem? Did I do something wrong?

Here is my code

```
webView = WebView(requireContext()).apply {
            settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
            settings.domStorageEnabled = true
            webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
                override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView?, url: String?) {
                    super.onPageFinished(view, url)
                    \\ Do something
                }

                override fun onReceivedError(
                    view: WebView?,
                    request: WebResourceRequest?,
                    error: WebResourceError?
                ) {
                    super.onReceivedError(view, request, error)
                    \\ Do something
                }
            }
            loadUrl(url)
        }
```

Comment: Why didnot you tell that onReceivedError was called instead? Or not?

Comment: Hello @blackapps, no onReceivedError is not called. I have specified that ```all functions I overrided in WebViewClient are not called.```. Usually, onPageFinished should be called after onReceivedError. But in my case, both of them are not invoked. Do you have any idea? Thanks